# What is the best method to store 672 boolean values in the SQL db with django?

Tags: python, django, performance, memory

I want to store a variable contains 672 boolean values in the sql database using django.
I used models.TextField to store this variable. I want to use less memory as possible to reduce the processing time, so it is the best way or there is another one to store such variable?
Thanks

Comment: Check out storing your boolean values in a [BitArray](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitArrays).

Comment: Trying to micro-optimize here is nonsense. Have you profiled your use-case? Is the DB really the bottleneck?

Comment: What do the booleans *represent*?

Comment: @Monkpit I want to use django fields

Comment: @deets I want to optimize the DB because I will many variables like this

Comment: @Sayse I have a function will be executed 672 times, I want the results be stored in one variable

Comment: Why? That sounds like an absolute nightmare.

Comment: A pickled list/tuple/dict is another option

Answer (score 0):

The method I would suggest to answer your question as-is would be to use a [BitArray](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitArrays).

```
>>> from random import getrandbits
>>> def get_n_bools(n):
...    count = 0
...    while count < n:
...        yield getrandbits(1)
...        count += 1
>>> from bitarray import bitarray
>>> ba = bitarray()
>>> ba.extend(get_n_bools(672))
>>> ba.tobytes()
'\xdd#\xa4_N\xcb\x94\\\\Q\xf02\x13Ov\xf4\xee=Jw\xef\xcf\x9co\xac"\xa8\xab\x1bam\xc6W[\x94\x125B\x1e\x9a\x85|\xe7\x0eQ\xe2\x010\xf4\xad\xa4\r\xc1\xef6e\x0b\x9a\xbb\xb7\xa9\x83\xc3\xfa\xb1\xffUbu\xfe\x10\x8d\x16\xdcS\x808\x99\xc1CQ&N\xd0'
>>> getsizeof(ba.tobytes())
105
```

Use `tobytes()` and store the value in a [Django BinaryField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#binaryfield).

#### Aside:

You should reconsider whether storing the values this way is necessary - perhaps you can post your code for review on [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) and get some feedback about your program's design.

Also, consider the questions the commenters have brought up:

- Why does the value have to be stored as one variable?
- Are you optimizing your program too early in the process?
- Has the program been run and it is indeed too slow, or does it run fine? How fast does the program need to be?
- Can you design the program in a different way to avoid the issue altogether?